# Why the dummy variable $y$ in the calculation of the gaussian integral as follows?

Tags: gaussian-integral

[image]

I don't understand why you have to use a different variable when squared the first integral? It is commonly glossed over to explain this.

Comment: Otherwise you couldn't write it as a double integral

Comment: Thank you but why is this a legal operation? Isn't it actually an $x$ in disguise?

Comment: @bananenheld This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2836395/144421) might help. Btw, it is not forbidden to accept answers. Check your previous questions.

Comment: thank you callculus42. I have accepted answers.